# pandas dataframe concat using for loop not working

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, concatenation

Here I am trying to concat dataframe A and B with C using a for loop.

```
data = [['Alex',10],['Bob',12],['Clarke',13]]

A = pd.Dataframe(data, columns=['Name','Age'])
B = pd.Dataframe(data, columns=['Name','Age'])
C = pd.Dataframe(data, columns=['Name','Age'])

A.columns  ---> Index(['Name', 'Age'], dtype='object')
B.columns  ---> Index(['Name', 'Age'], dtype='object')
C.columns  ---> Index(['Name', 'Age'], dtype='object')

for df in [A, B]:
    df = pd.concat([df, C], axis=1)

A.columns  ---> Index(['Name', 'Age'], dtype='object')
B.columns  ---> Index(['Name', 'Age'], dtype='object')
df.columns ---> Index(['Name', 'Age', 'Name', 'Age'], dtype='object')
```

**Why its not concatenating C with original A, B dataframes. Why it is creating a new df Dataframe?**

I want after for loop:

```
A.columns ---> Index(['Name', 'Age', 'Name', 'Age'], dtype='object')
B.columns ---> Index(['Name', 'Age', 'Name', 'Age'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using Python mappings of names to object differently than how they work (you might be confused by other languages' references).

When you use

```
for df in [A, B]:
    df = pd.concat([df, C], axis=1)
```

Then `df` on the right side means "the object mapped to by the name `df`" (that is, `A` then `B`). `df` on the left side is just the *name* `df`.  Your loop is therefore not modifying the original objects at all.

---

You can use

```
A, B = pd.concat([A, C], axis=1), pd.concat([B, C], axis=1)
```

If you really must use a loop, you can use a `dict`. First place the object there,

```
dfs = {'A': A, 'B': B}
```

then refer to them only through the `dict`:

```
for k, v in dfs.items():
    dfs[k] = pd.concat([v, C], axis=1)
```

Comment: Agreed, a loop probably isn't ideal here. I'd add two suggestions to Ami's answer: First, you could use a list instead of a dict (change to dfs = [A,B] and for k, v in enumerate(dfs)). Second, you could also do it as a comprehension instead of a for loop. As a list comprehension this would be dfs = [pd.concat([x, C], axis = 1) for x in [A,B]]