# Python/Pandas. For loop on multiple dataFrames not working correctly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, concatenation

I am trying to process a list of dataframes (example shows 2, reality has much more) in multiple ways using a for loop.
Droping columns in the dataframe referenced in the loop works fine, however, concat doesn't do anything inside the loop. I expect to update the original dataframe referenced in dfs.

UPDATED PROBLEM STATEMENT

Previous examples do not cover this case/ seem to not work.
Example adapted from here: [pandas dataframe concat using for loop not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50306898/pandas-dataframe-concat-using-for-loop-not-working)

Minifying the example leads to the following (code partially borrowed from another question)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


data = [['Alex',10],['Bob',12],['Clarke',13]]
data2 = ['m','m','x']
A = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name','Age'])
B = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name','Age'])
C = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['Gender'])

#expected result for A:
Anew=pd.DataFrame([['Alex','m'],['Bob','m'],['Clarke','x']], columns=['Name', 'Gender'])

dfs = [A,B]

for k, v in enumerate(dfs):
    # The following line works as expected on A an B respectively, inplace is required to actually modify A,B as defined above
    dfs[k]=v.drop('Age',axis=1, inplace=True)
    # The following line doesn't do anything, I was expecting Anew (see above) 
    dfs[k] = pd.concat([v, C], axis=1)
    # The following line prints the expected result within the loop
    print(dfs[k])

# This just shows A, not Anew: To me tha tmeans A was never updated with dfs[k] as I thought it would. 
print(A)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Try:

```
data = [['Alex',10],['Bob',12],['Clarke',13]]
data2 = ['m','m','x']
A = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name','Age'])
B = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name','Age'])
C = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['Gender'])
Anew = pd.DataFrame([['Alex','m'],['Bob','m'],['Clarke','x']], columns=['Name', 'Gender'])

dfs = [A, B]
for v in dfs:
    v.drop('Age', axis=1, inplace=True)
    v['Gender'] = C
print(A)
print(Anew)
```

Output:

```
>>> A
     Name Gender
0    Alex      m
1     Bob      m
2  Clarke      x

>>> Anew
     Name Gender
0    Alex      m
1     Bob      m
2  Clarke      x
```

---

If you use `inplace=True`, Pandas doesn't return a DataFrame so `dfs` is now `None`:

```
dfs[k]=v.drop('Age', axis=1, inplace=True)  # <- Remove inplace=True
```

Try:

```
dfs = [A, B]
for k, v in enumerate(dfs):
    dfs[k] = v.drop('Age', axis=1)
    dfs[k] = pd.concat([v, C], axis=1)
out = pd.concat([A, C], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
     Name  Age Gender
0    Alex   10      m
1     Bob   12      m
2  Clarke   13      x
```

Comment: Thank you, however, I believe this does not solve the problem at hand (see updated statement).
the concat within the for loop doesn't do anything to the actual dataframes A and B
Doing it manually after the for loop works, but defeats the purpose of the for in the first place.

Comment: I updated my answer. I wonder if you really need pd.concat.

Comment: In this case you don't. However, it is a simplified case. C has multiple columns, which are determined in another part of the loop. Hence my desire to concat two dataframes. However, I could use another loop to add the content of C columnwise as described. Seems clunky:/

Comment: I know but if you want to modify dataframes in place, you don't have much solution :-(

Comment: Final note to move on:
Upvoted this as a solution. Thank you.  However, I am still surprised that concat cannot be used to solve the problem at hand. 
Final solution involves a simple for col in C.columns: dfs[k][col]=C[col]

Comment: FYI, `inplace` parameter will be deprecated in future version of Pandas: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529.